# Coldfusion Server: Issues when an email is generated that does not get sent

Tags: coldfusion

Basically when an email is generated in our ColdFusion application sometimes an email gets hung in the system because of some error, maybe an email address wasn't specified or something like that. So my boss is having me check the ColdFusion8\Mail\Spool directory every morning for a email(s) if they exist, restart the ColdFusion8 Application Server service then delete the emails.

Issue: System gets email that hangs up, system stops sending emails all together for every email form.

Is there a automated way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two suggestions.  Wrap the cfmail call in a cftry and make sure you are checking the email address with `IsValid("email", someEmailAddress)`

In my experience this eliminates 95% (ish) of the hang ups.  Sometimes the problem is with the email gateway and not with coldfusion.  In this case there may be nothing you can do depending on the setup.

Answer (score 2):

The Undelivernator project on RIAForge.org is what you're looking for.

http://undelivrnator.riaforge.org/

Answer (score 1):

I've rolled my own tools to do this several times.

Basically, you need a scheduled job to look in the Undelivr directory and move all of the files to Spool. Easy enough to accomplish with CFDIRECTORY, CFFILE, a loop, and about twenty lines of code.

Other considerations include

- permanently abandon re-sending a message after X days
- e-mailing or publishing a report of messages re-spooled and abandoned

I seem to write (at least) one of these at every new job site. [The Deliverinator mentioned by scrittler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730298/coldfusion-server-issues-when-an-email-is-generated-that-does-not-get-sent/4730510#4730510) seems interesting, although my solution never bothered with a RDBMS.